# Session not working in 3rd file of php script

Tags: php, html, oracle

I have 3 files (m1.php, m2.php, m3.php)

m1 code:

```
    <?php  session_start();     //starting the session ?>   
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
       <strong> Enter Phone Number: </strong>
         <form action="m2.php" method = "POST">
           <input type="text" name="ph"/>
           <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>

     <?php 
       if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
       $_SESSION['ph'] = $_POST['ph'];
    } 
   ?> 
     </html>
```

m2 code:

```
     <?php session_start(); ?>
        <html>
         <body> Details of:
            <strong>
              <?php 
                echo $_POST['ph'];
                $_SESSION['phone'] = $_POST['ph'];
             ?>
            </strong>
         <?php
              $ph = $_SESSION['phone'];
              $link = oci_connect('hd','hd', 'localhost/mydb');
               if(!$link) {
                  $e = oci_error();
                  exit('Connection error    ' . $e['message']);
                }
               $q1 = "select CUST_ID from customer where CUST_PHONE = :bv_ph";
               $q1parse = oci_parse($link, $q1);
               oci_bind_by_name($q1parse, ':bv_ph', $phone);
               oci_execute($q1parse);
               oci_fetch($q1parse);
               $res = oci_result($q1parse, 'CUST_ID');
               if(!$res) {
                   echo "No Order found. New Order?";
               }
          ?>
        <?php
            if(isset($_POST['option']) && ($_POST['option']) == "Yes") {
                    header("Location: m3.php");
            }
            elseif(isset($_POST['option']) && ($_POST['option']) == "No") {
                    header("location: m1.php");
            }

            $q2 = "select A.ADDRESS, A.AREA from customer c 
              join customer_address ca on C.CUST_ID = CA.CUST_ID
              join address a on A.ADDRESS_ID = CA.ADDRESS_ID where C.CUST_ID = :id_bv";
            $q2parse = oci_parse($link, $q2);
            oci_bind_by_name($q2parse, ':id_bv', $res);
            oci_execute($q2parse);
            while($row = oci_fetch_array($q2parse)) {
                    echo "<tr><td>" . htmlentities($row["ADDRESS"]) . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . htmlentities($row["AREA"]) . "</td></tr>";
            }
             oci_free_statement($q2parse);
             oci_close($link);

         ?>

        <form action = "" method = "POST" >
            <input type = "radio" name = "option" value = "Yes" checked> Yes <br>
            <input type = "radio" name = "option" value ="No"> No <br>
            <input type = "submit" value = "submit">
        </form>
         <table border = "black">
            <tr> 
                <th> ADDRESS </th>
                <th> AREA </th>
            </tr>
         </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

m3 code:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <?php
    echo $_SESSION['phone'];
    ?>
</html>
```

The problem is that the session variable ($_SESSION['phone']) works in m2.php but it does not display in m3.php. It just displays nothing. My main aim is to take the phone number and 1st check in the database. If it exists then display the information else add the no. in the database along with other details like name, address etc. I am trying to use sessions for this but the above problem is not making me do it. Stuck on this since long time.Help Please!

Also, if I use the same thing without the form in m2.php, it works perfectly.

Comment: the opening php tag in m1 is wrong - also in m2 there is a space before the php tag

Comment: These mistakes happened while copy pasting the code. These are not present in the actual code.

Comment: perhaps you ought to fix the code above so that others might see the real problem then

Comment: The m1 mistake is corrected.

Answer (score 0):

You should write the `echo $_SESSION['phone'];` inside body tag

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
   <body>
        <?php
           echo $_SESSION['phone'];
        ?>
   </body>
</html>
```

To see any result you have to put that inside `<body>` tag

Comment: I did it, but still no result

Comment: Yes I did it, but still no result. Also, when I do it without the form in m2, it works perfectly, without the <body> tag.

Comment: I have tested and it's working fine. No issue with that.

Comment: You need to provide the value in m1.php and then submit. Then only you will get the session variable.

Comment: yeah I know that, im doing that only.

Comment: It does work fine in m2.php as shown in the above link. The problem is with m3. In m3.php it shows nothing, No errors, nothing. Just plain page.

Comment: Already given you the m3.php code which works. Still you are facing issue then check your server.

Comment: I am using xamp. I have no idea how to check the problem.